# How to make fancy box center after resize using left property

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have the below code in fancy box content. I have the link which will call another fancy box iframe. The second page width and height will be different from first iframe page. So i  re-size  the fancy box iframe using following code in second page,

```
   jQuery(function(){
                        //jQuery('div[id^=fancybox]').remove();
                        jQuery('#fancybox-frame', window.parent.document).load(function() { 
                            parent_fb_resize(560,444);            
                            jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').css('margin','auto');                    
                        });                            
});
```

Re size the iframe using below code,

```
function parent_fb_resize(w, h) {  
  if (w > 0 || h > 0) {

    if (w > 0) jQuery('div#fancybox-wrap', window.parent.document).css({ width: (w)+"px"});
    if (h > 0) jQuery('div#fancybox-wrap', window.parent.document).css({ height: (h)+"px"});
    if (w > 0) jQuery('#fancybox-content', window.parent.document).css({ width: w+"px"});
    if (h > 0) jQuery('#fancybox-content', window.parent.document).css({ height: h+"px"});
    jQuery.fancybox.resize();
    jQuery.fancybox.center();

  }
}
function fb_close_any() {
  window.top.eval('jQuery.fancybox.close()');
}

function fb_resize_any(w, h) {
  w = (w > 0) ? w : 0;
  h = (h > 0) ? h : 0;
  window.top.eval('fb_resize('+w+','+h+')');
}
```

So far so good. This code resize the second page. But the re sized fancy box is not in center position due to left property in **id** `fancybox-wrap`

```
{
display: block;
height: 444px;
left: 271px;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 20px;
width: 560px;
}
```

Here i need to find the center of the page and need to apply left position dynamically in `jQuery('#fancybox-frame', window.parent.document).load()`. Kindly give advice on this ?

Comment: Also jQuery.fancybox.center(); is not even working.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `left: 271px;` even there in the css? Its not required for centering an element, thats what `margin: 0 auto;` does. I would suggest just getting rid of it as that is likely your problem.

Here is a Jsfiddle to demonstrate what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/fPqqT/

If you cant get rid of the left css, maybe set it to 0px when you do the resize?

```
$("#fancybox-wrap").css("left", 0);
```